# Using own implementation of HashSet.add()

Tags: java, performance, data-structures, hash, hashset

I am using a HashSet to add unique Users to the hashset. These users are updated frequently from an online source and when it reads it in from there it gets a new object each time so all the Users get added again.

I have a UserID variable in my user class and would like to use this to add users to the HashSet and ensure uniqueness.

```
private HashSet<User> userHashSet = new HashSet<User>();

userHashSet.add(user);
//based on the users id it will either add or not
```

I want to do this without losing efficiency and preferably only one HashSet

Answer (score 4):

You should implement the `equals` and `hashCode` method in your `User` class.

As an example:

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return getUserId().hashCode();
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    return obj instanceof User &&
        getUserId().equals(((User) obj).getUserId());
}
```

Comment: That was exactly the solution! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement the `hashCode` and `equals` methods in your `User` class. So long as you implement those two methods correctly then you will get unique entries in your `HashSet`.

There are many articles about how to implement these correctly (e.g. [What issues should be considered when overriding equals and hashCode in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581/what-issues-should-be-considered-when-overriding-equals-and-hashcode-in-java)), but the easiest way to do it is to get your IDE to auto-generate those methods, or use the Apache Commons helpers.